# Angular directive for show more / show less

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-directive, angular7

I have the following on an Angular 7 application to show / hide more elements ([Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqer3o)):

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li *ngIf ="hidden">Item 3</li>
 <li *ngIf ="hidden">Item 4</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" (click)="hidden = !hidden"> {{hidden ? 'show less' : 'show more'}}</a>
```

**Questions**

1. Can this be done with a directive?

   This is something I use often. I am not sure if a directive can do this and how.
2. In Angular 2+ is ok to define variables, e.g. hidden, in HTML without a Component?

   I could use a component with variable hidden but isn't to much for something as simple?

Comment: You can use ViewChildren https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren in your directive (remember implements AfterViewInit), so make invisibles or not the elements. For this, inject Rendered2 to add/Remove attribute display:none

Answer (score 0):

You could make a base Component to realize that.
In the base component you could add your `hidden` variable and eventually you can expose a method to alter `hidden` variabile value.

By this way all your extending components will have `hidden` variable.
But if you don't need anything else and your `hidden` variable is updated simply with a boolean value (`this.hidden = true` or `this.hidden = false`) you will not have any other advantages.

Finally keep in mind that the button (or whatelse you want to use) to update `hidden` variable value will have to stay into subcomponents'template files.

With this scenario I think your solution is the best one, but if you want to complicate a bit your approach you could use

- a small `HideButtonComponent` with only "show less" / "show more" button
- a `HideService` that contains your `hidden` variable (updated by the `HideButtonComponent`)

Then into your components you could inject `HideService` in the constructors and subscribe to `hidden` variable changes.
Into your components' template files you could place your `HideButtonComponent` to avoid to duplicate the button code

But I repeat: it is a very small advantage